# the outdated script is being executed according to Python traceback

Tags: python, traceback

I've encountered a weird issue regrading the tracebacks in python. I've updated some code but while debugging, it's still using the outdated code. detailed traceback as below:

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "~/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xxx/xmlrpc/dispatcher.py", line 95, in _marshaled_dispatch
    response = self._dispatch(method, params)  
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/SimpleXMLRPCServer.py", line 420, in _dispatch
    return func(*params)  
  File "~/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kobo/hub/decorators.py", line 24, in _new_func  
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)  
  File "~/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myapp/worker.py", line 61, in register  
    download.save()
```

I'm pretty sure the exception thrown by `download.save()` is already removed. i.e., the line 61 in `~/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myapp/worker.py` **doesn't contain** `download.save()`:

```
$ grep -r "download.save" ~/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myapp/
```

no matchings found.

but it looks python still uses the out-dated code. my new changes still won't work.
besides, I've also removed the worker.pyc file under the save directory before running the scripts.

any ideas how to resolve the issue?

Comment: problem still exists even if re-initialize the whole virtualenv.

Comment: actually the traceback as posted above are wrong and outdated. it's obtained from some server log, even if the code is updated, the traceback(parsed from some log file on disk) remains there.

Comment: I've flagged the question as `too localized`, it's not constructive, please close.

Answer (score 1):

When you grep, and when you run the code, are they as the same user? Is the code running under a web server or similar daemon process, with a different username and a different home directory?

Comment: it's a virtualenv in my home directory and the code/process owned by me. yeah it's a daemon process I've restarted the daemon before applying my changes. but the daemon still uses the outdated code.

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove all precompiled .pyc files?

Comment: thanks for the attention, already tried but to no avail. the `pyc` would update automatically upon `py` file updates I guess.